# Schedule periodic tasks in Java, avoid creating new threads until necessary (like CachedThreadPool)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scheduled-tasks, threadpool

I have a number of tasks that I would like to execute periodically at different rates for most tasks. Some of the tasks may be scheduled for simultaneous execution though. Also, a task may need to start executing while another is currently executing.

I would also like to customize each task by setting an object for it, on which the task will operate while it is being executed.

Usually, the tasks will execute in periods of 2 to 30 minutes and will take around 4-5 seconds, sometimes up to 30 seconds when they are executed.

I've found `Executors.newSingleThreadedScheduledExecutor(ThreadFactory)` to be almost exactly what I want, except that it might cause me problems if a new task happens to be scheduled for execution while another is already executing. This is due to the fact that the Executor is backed up by a single execution thread.

The alternative is to use `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(corePoolSize, ThreadFactory)`, but this requires me to create a number of threads in a pool. I would like to avoid creating threads until it is necessary, for instance if I have two or more tasks that happen to need parallell executing due to their colliding execution schedules.

For the case above, the `Executors.newCachedThreadPool(ThreadFactory)` appears to do what I want, but then I can't schedule my tasks. A combination of both cached and scheduled executors would be best I think, but I am unable to find something like that in Java.

What would be the best way to implement the above do you think?

Comment: You can see [Quartz Scheduler API](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/).

Comment: Idle threads have next to no cost. If resources is you only concern I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you for you response. This sounds good, and I am leaning more and more towards using ScheduledExecutorService with a few threads in the pool (will have to research the optimum pool size). My main concern is to avoid a task having to wait to execute, due to another task being currently executed by the executor.

Comment: To give you some idea, you JVM can have about 20 threads just running HelloWorld. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know that it might sound as I am applying premature optimization, but I will be using quite a lot of threads in the later stages of my project and I am trying to keep the thread count low if it is possible :)

Comment: You could try sharing your thread pools or having one pass to another. e.g. have a single scheduler (globally) which passes all tasks to a single cached thread pool.

Comment: If the tasks make any blocking calls, (eg. network stuff), you will need more idle threads, not less, to try an ensure that a new task gets scheduled onto a thread as soon as it's queued up.  If the tasks are CPU-intensive and do not block, you're stuffed anyway once all cores are running existing tasks.  I don't see much point in restricting the number of pool threads to less than the number of cores in any case, CPU-intensive or not.

Comment: Peter, I like the idea of shared thread pools, I will definately look into it. Also, would you mind showing an example of a single scheduler passing tasks to a cached thread pool? I can't get my head around that at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor%28int%29):

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(0);
```

what you need? `0` is the `corePoolSize`:

> `corePoolSize` - the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idle, unless `allowCoreThreadTimeOut` is set

Comment: Not sure: "*Additionally, it is almost never a good idea to set corePoolSize to zero or use allowCoreThreadTimeOut because this may leave the pool without threads to handle tasks once they become eligible to run.*"

Comment: @assylias: +1, good catch. But this only means that once the task is eligible, executor will have to start new thread, which takes time. If this is the only issue, seems like the OP can live with that (he wants as little threads as possible and nothing idle). We'll see, but thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't mind having a thread or two in the pool and idling. My bigger concern is to guarantee a task is being executed as scheduled, even though another task is currently being executed. Also, finding the right pool size when not using a single scheduled executor is an issue.

Comment: @veroslav - you can't have it both ways.  If there are no threads left in the pool, a new task cannot be dispatched onto a thread without creating a new thread.

Comment: @Martin: You're right and it makes perfect sense. I will simply have to find an appropriate thread pool size and be done with it. Thanks for all of the thoughts and suggestions each of you posted, they were helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will not able to do that with `ScheduledExecutor`, because it uses [DelayedWorkQueue](http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/pub/swm/jdoc6/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.DelayedWorkQueue.html) where as `newCachedThreadPool` uses `ThreadPoolExecutor` [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) as a work queue.

So you can not change implementation of [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) to act like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That seems to be correct and if I must make a choice between the two, I am going to pick ScheduledExecutor with a appropriate thread pool size, because it greatly simplifies scheduling of the tasks, which is my main priority at the moment.

Comment: Waiting threads will not cause you much harm since they will not consume any processor space. They will only consume heap space so you can keep a considerable count for `ScheduledExecutor`.

Comment: That feels good to know, the resources used by idling threads was one of my main concerns as I thought that they were "waiting" in some "run()" method ready to execute. Glad to hear that it is not the case.